# Using utf8mb4 with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have read that mysql >= 5.5.3 fully supports every possible character if you USE the encoding **utf8mb4** for a certain table/column http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

looks nice. Only I noticed that the mb_functions in php does not! I cannot find it anywhere in the list: http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php

Not only have I read things but I also made a test.

I have added data to a mysql utf8mb4 table using a php script where the internal encoding was set to UTF-8: `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");`

and, as expected, the characters looks messy once in the db.

Any idea how I can make php and mysql talk the same encoding (possibly a 4 bytes one) and still have FULL support to any world language?

Also why is utf8mb4 different from utf32?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manipulating utf8mb4 data from MySQL with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028537/manipulating-utf8mb4-data-from-mysql-with-php)

Comment: How to convert variable (text/string) to utf8mb4 in php https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46873897/how-to-convert-variable-text-string-to-utf8mb4-in-php

Answer (score 41):

MySQL's `utf8` encoding is *not* actual UTF-8. It's an encoding that is kinda like UTF-8, but only supports a subset of what UTF-8 supports. `utf8mb4` is *actual* UTF-8. This difference is an **internal implementation detail** of MySQL. Both look like UTF-8 on the PHP side. Whether you use `utf8` or `utf8mb4`, PHP will get valid UTF-8 in both cases.

What you need to make sure is that the *connection encoding* between PHP and MySQL is set to `utf8mb4`. If it's set to `utf8`, MySQL will not support all characters. You set this connection encoding using `mysql_set_charset()`, the PDO `charset` DSN connection parameter or whatever other method is appropriate for your database API of choice.

---

`mb_internal_encoding` just sets the default value for the `$encoding` parameter all `mb_*` functions have. It has nothing to do with MySQL.

UTF-8 and UTF-32 differ in how they encode characters. UTF-8 uses a *minimum* of 1 byte for a character and a maximum of 4. UTF-32 *always* uses 4 bytes for every character. UTF-16 uses a minimum of 2 bytes and a maximum of 4.
Due to its variable length, UTF-8 has a little bit of overhead. A character which can be encoded in 2 bytes in UTF-16 may take 3 or 4 in UTF-8; on the other hand, UTF-16 never uses *less* than 2 bytes. If you're storing lots of Asian text, UTF-16 may use less storage. If most of your text is English/ASCII, UTF-8 uses less storage. UTF-32 always uses the most storage.

Comment: "What you need to make sure is that the connection encoding between PHP and MySQL is set to utf8mb4". Right ... I have not done that! That must be the reason.

Comment: Is it up to four or six? Joel Spolsky's article on this says 6: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @Tommy That's old and deprecated information. 6 isn't used in practice and has been discontinued.

Comment: so UTF-8 changed? It wasn't a standard? (I'm trying to understand this mess all now)

Comment: The problem is with this is that if we're stuck with mysql UTF8, are we not unable to validate strings in PHP for MySQL without using the database? Wont a stringthat reads as valid UTF8 in PHP potentially have unrecognised sequences nuked in mysql?

Comment: @jgmjgm You should know whether your MySQL instance supports `utf8mb4` or not. That's an important dependency and needs to be nailed down for your project. If it does support `utf8mb4`, then there should be no issue. If you only have `utf8` to work with, your application only supports BMP characters and you need to enforce/ensure that somewhere in your application layer. Or you switch to BLOB storage in MySQL and deal with the fallout of *that* in your application layer. Either way you should never be in a situation to leave that up to chance.

Comment: deceze, I refer to the situation where you have utfmb3 in mysql and it's not anything you can change quickly. There's no utf8mb3 validation in PHP. 'you need to enforce/ensure that somewhere in your' that's the annoyance. BMP and simply contraining to 3 bytes achieve the same. It's a kudgle where you'll likely want to use your own validation rather than purely mb_check_encoding. It can be difficult to switch to mb3 in mysql not only due to it being a large code change but it can also cause fields to hit index length limit.

Answer (score 13):

This is what i used, and worked good for my problem using euro € sign and conversion for json_encode failure.

**php configurations script( api etc..)**

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
ini_set("default_charset", "UTF-8");
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
iconv_set_encoding("internal_encoding", "UTF-8");
iconv_set_encoding("output_encoding", "UTF-8");
```

**mysql tables / or specific columns**

```
utf8mb4
```

**mysql PDO connection**

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=yourip;dbname=XYZ;charset=utf8mb4';
```

(...your connection ...)

**before execute query (might not be required):**

```
$dbh->exec("set names utf8mb4");
```

Comment: This isnt accurate though. If you are using 'set names utf8' then your connection is speaking to mysql in just a subset of *real* utf8. You need to 'set names utf8mb4' to speak in the full utf8 character set (including passing emojis). Otherwise mysql will often truncate a string at the point it encounters a utf character which is > 3 bytes

Comment: Super helpful. All I had to do was to set the `charset` to `utf8mb4` instead of `utf8`. Now my mysql database reads and writes emojis with no issues 

Comment: setting iconv encoding seems to be deprecated now.

Answer (score 4):

- utf-32: This is a character encoding using a fixed 4-bytes per characters
- utf-8: This is a character encoding using up to 4 bytes per characters, but the most frequent characters are coded on only 1, 2 or 3 characters.

MySQL's utf-8 doesn't support characters coded on more than 3 characters, so they added utf-8mb4, which is really utf-8.

Answer (score 4):

Before running your actual query, do a mysql_query ('SET NAMES utf8mb4')

Also make sure your mysql server is configured to use utf8mb4 too. For more information on how, refer to article: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#utf8-to-utf8mb4