# Php script to Import CSV with Arabic content

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import, arabic

I have to build a script to import a CSV file, (With Arabic content in one coloumn).

I have been searching online and manage to convert my CSV file to UTF8

```
$filename = $_FILES["csv"]["tmp_name"];

$file = fopen($filename, "r");

$count = 0;
while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
{
$count++;
if($count>1){

// tried to convert using below
$string_decoded =  iconv("windows-1256", "utf-8", $emapData[2]);
// convert code above

$sql = "INSERT into `$table` (SurahNo,AyatNo,Ayat) values ('$emapData[0]','$emapData[1]','$string_decoded')";
echo $sql;
mysql_query($sql);  
}
}
```

I tried to convert using iconv but still getting garbage content imported in mysql.

Imported content look like this
Ø·Â¨Ø¸Ú¯Ø·Â³Ø¸â€™Ø¸â€¦Ø¸Ú¯ Ø·Â§Ø¸â€žØ¸â€žØ¸â€˜Ø¸

Can share my CSV file if you wish.

Need help, spend hours searching.

Comment: Your mysql table supports utf8?

Comment: yes, this is my database look like

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `halar_table` (
  `SurahNo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AyatNo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Ayat` varchar(1000) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: is the echoed sql displayed correctly or does error appears there too?

Comment: I thik you need to set your connection charset. I would recommend also to use mysqli or PDO for your database operations. see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893035/using-utf8mb4-with-php-and-mysql

Comment: echo showing error too. that's what display when echo
INSERT into `halar_table` (SurahNo,AyatNo,Ayat) values ('1','1','Ø·Â¨Ø¸Ú¯Ø·Â³Ø¸â€™Ø¸â€¦Ø¸Ú¯ Ø·Â§Ø¸â€žØ¸â€žØ¸â€˜Ø¸Ú˜Ø¸â€¡Ø¸Ú¯ Ø·Â§Ø¸â€žØ·Â±Ø¸â€˜Ø¸Ú˜Ø·Â­Ø¸â€™Ø¸â€¦Ø¸Ú˜Ø¸Â°Ø¸â€ Ø¸Ú¯ Ø·Â§Ø¸â€žØ·Â±Ø¸â€˜Ø¸Ú˜Ø·Â­Ø¸Ú¯Ø¸Ù¹Ø¸â€¦Ø¸Ú¯')

Comment: So it's seems to be a problem with fgets() function. Could you provide the file or an extract with few lines?

Comment: Sorry just notice you came back to me, you need line of my import file or csv file?