# FPDF with iconv from utf8mb4

Tags: php, character-encoding, fpdf, utf8mb4

I have a string coming from MySql DB, encoded in utf8mb4. I am rendering a pdf with FPDF for PHP, and I tried to convert it with iconv:

```
iconv('utf8mb4', 'cp1252',$myString);
```

This fails telling me "Notice: iconv(): Wrong charset, conversion from `utf8mb4' to`cp1252' is not allowed".
If I try with

```
iconv('utf-8', 'cp1252',$myString);
```

I get "Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string".

Without iconv I get multiple ascii chars in place of special chars, and it is not fine.

Is there any way to output this value correctly?

Comment: Looks like you miss a `'` after `utf8`

Comment: A typo not present in original code - corrected in question

Comment: I think this might be of some help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893035/using-utf8mb4-with-php-and-mysql

Comment: Have you checked that `$myString` is utf8 encoded?

Comment: $myString comes from a select on a mysql table with utf8mb4 charset, on a connection estabilished with utf8mb4: db->set_charset("utf8mb4")

Answer (score 1):

try this one to IGNORE character which is not allowed in the charset

```
iconv('utf-8', 'cp1252//IGNORE',$myString);
```

Comment: This would just jump "strange" characters, not represent them correctly

Answer (score 0):

I tried, it did't work. I solved this by using a version of FPDF that allows utf8: TFPDF. It is fully retrocompatible, provided that you add its new font (ttf).