# Charset UTF-8 and php header() not working

Tags: php, html, utf-8, character-encoding

I am having some problems with the charset on my website. I can't get the UTF-8 charset to work and I get �  instead of Å. Yes, I have searched around the web for answers and I've already used the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset=utf-8" />
    <title><?php echo $db_title; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
    Some content with letters æøå
</body>
</html>
```

The database uses `latin1_swedish_ci`.

Any idea what it could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Set the PHP `header` tag before any output to the browser (as pointed out by JJ Cantillon)
- While PHP and HTML use the correct UTF-8, it is worth noting that MySQL uses a reduced version of UTF-8 and so when selecting the Collation of the database tables/fields the "utf8_general_ci" (and similar) are ***not*** full character sets and so your characters you want to display will not be stored correctly.

What you need to do is to ensure MySQL uses the complete UTF-8 character set by selecting

> Collation = 'utf8mb4'

Also, when you are connecting your script to the database you need to specify the same (`utf8mb4`) character set for PHP/MySQL communication - so set something like (in as far as MySQLi or PDO etc.)

```
new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;charset=utf8mb4')
```

or for MySQLi read up on http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

If you store data in the SQL as `utf8mb4` but only transfer the data using standard MySQL-utf8 (3bytes rather than 4bytes) then the character sets will be screwed up in transport.

Reading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16893103/3536236

Comment: Great to know, I haven't created the insert system yet, but this will definitly keep me ahead of future problems :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set the header before you output any html.

Try to set the header before your first HTML tag. EG:

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset=utf-8" />
    <title><?php echo $db_title; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
    Some content with letters æøå
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I solved the problem by changing the charset in the database connection. There must have been a host update, since it hasn't affected the site before.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. Good to hear you worked it out.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching I came across the following [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361459/php-pdo-charset-set-names) In the database connection I had to specify that I wanted the UTF-8 charset. I did it the following way:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=NAME;charset=utf8', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD');
```

It must have been a server update from the host that caused the problem, since I haven't been affected by the problem before now.

Comment: You actually want `utf8mb4` rather than standard utf8 in MySQL.