# Content-Type charset won't change

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, cyrillic, charset

I'm trying to change my website from windows-1251 to utf-8, but it won't budge.

There are a ton of "solutions" to this on web, but any doesn't seem to be sufficient.

Here is what I did:

1. I changed the encoding of the index.html (smarty template) and index.php files to UTF-8.
2. I set

   ```
    <html lang="ru">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   ```

in index.html

3. I set

   ```
   header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
   ```

in several places in index.php

4. I changed

   ```
   default_charset="UTF-8"
   ```

in php.ini and restarted my Apache(XAMPP) server

And still, the Chrome devtools say my page is "`Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251`" and I see gibberish instead of Cyrillic in my browser.

What else can I do?

P.S. my index.html looks like this now:

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        Тест
    </body>
</html>
```

and I open it dirrectly via the browser: http://localhost:8080/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared I had a Chrome encoding extension installed, which was set to Windows-1251: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/set-character-encoding/bpojelgakakmcfmjfilgdlmhefphglae

Comment: So one workaround which you didn't consider was: use a different client (web browser). Maybe you even encounter one that already comes with the possibility to let the user choose the encoding - maybe _Safari_ still allows this...

Answer (score 0):

Check this url. This might help you.
[charset changing](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-changing-encoding)

Edit:
Try these.

1. Set the header before HTML tags.

   `<?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>`
   `<!DOCTYPE html>`
2. when you connect your script to the database you need to specify the same character set for PHP/MySQL connection.
   Check
   [Old issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32967768/charset-utf-8-and-php-header-not-working)

Comment: i checked it before the post. Do you mean anything specific?

Comment: @klm123 Edited the answer. Please check.

Comment: 1. doesn't help. 2. there is no database anymore. it's just one index.html, which you can see in the post