# Codeigniter not accepting "utf8mb4" as default charset

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, utf-8

Good day,

I am using Codeigniter to develop my webapp. 
PHP version on the server is 5.6.22 and Mysql version of the db is 5.6.27. 
In codeigniter's database.php when I change the charset to "utf8mb4" from "utf8", I get the following message .(image attached)

**Unable to set client connection character set: utf8mb4**

[image]

**UPDATE**
I can run the codeigniter app on another server that has the same php version and the same mysql version. So it must be something pertaining to httpd.conf or php.ini, maybe?

Comment: did your change the charset of your database in actual. To do so Please read this https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

Comment: Please see the update. Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem while trying to run migrations (using CI4/PHP 8.2.10/MySQL 8.2.0) . I solved it by editing the file 'app\Config\Database.php' and changing 'charset' and 'DBCollat' to 'charset'  => 'utf8mb4' and 'DBCollat'  => 'utf8mb4_spanish_ci'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to remove the bug by removing my php installation and installing the httpd and php again from scratch.

Answer (score 6):

In `database.php`

> > Set **`char_set` to `utf8mb4`** and **`dbcollat` to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` or `utf8_general_ci`**

---

**I tested this with my Codeigniter 3.0**

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8mb4',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',

);
```

And in controller I add this

```
$CI = &get_instance();
$CI->load->database();
echo $CI->db->char_set;
echo "<br>";
echo $CI->db->dbcollat;
```

**Output**

```
utf8mb4
utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

---

Read this

1. [Using utf8mb4 with php and mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893035/using-utf8mb4-with-php-and-mysql)

Comment: as i know there are nothing with the `php.ini` or `my.ini`(mysql)

Comment: Please see my updated question. Also I cannot test this in controller as it does not allow me to load view. Just give me the error as in screenshot.

Comment: @WarisAli are you still facung this issue??

Comment: No. Turns out although php5.5+ support utf8mb4, there are some versions that have some known issues with the char encoding of the type. I unistalled and installed the latest php and the error was gone. It was strange.

Comment: @WarisAli I'm using php 7. That's what i inform you early