# How to convert variable (text/string) to utf8mb4 in php

Tags: php, utf-8, utf8mb4, urdu

Hi I'm looking for a encode function for utf8mb4,

```
$var = = "نور";

echo utf8mb4_encode($string);

output = Ù†ÙˆØ± // its $var output in UTFMB4
```

The output should be "Ù†ÙˆØ±" this, its a conversion of $var in utfmb4

Comment: That's Mojibake.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return value of the mb_convert_encoding function could give you the desired result.

```
$string = "نور";
$result = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-8', 'Windows-1252');
//$result = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-8', 'Windows-1254');
echo $result;
```

Comment: Not its giving me this result "ÙÙØ±"

Comment: Looks like a Windows-1252 or Windows-1254 encoding, but I'm not sure. I've updated the example code.

Comment: Thanks a @Daniel now getting the same character of utfmb4, cheers

Answer (score 10):

mb_convert_encoding is the answer. another option is the [iconv function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) - but this is assuming $var is not already in utf8 - you must first find out what characterset $var is encoded in. and if your variable is indeed hardcoded into the PHP script itself, then either:

it's already utf-8 encoded

OR

your php script starts with

```
<?php
declare(encoding='ISO-8859-1');
```

(just replace ISO-8859-1 with whatever the actual encoding is)

OR

its a bug in your source code. (because PHP source code is UTF-8 encoded by default, unless otherwise specified with the encoding declaration)

assuming ISO-8859-1,  `$result = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');` / `$result=iconv('ISO-8859-1','UTF-8',$string);`

(PS, `utf8mb4` is NOT a character encoding, utf8mb4 is just MySQL's nickname for utf8. what MySQL calls `utf8` is actually a 3-byte subset of the real utf8. and what MySQL calls `utf8mb4` is the real utf8. its just some MySQL brain-damage. and unfortunately, MariaDB inherited this brain-damage from MySQL when it was forked.)